# Tag suggestion for "extraterrestrial"

Tags: discussion, tags

See the following questions relating to this tag:

https://biology.stackexchange.com/search?q=extraterrestrial

Which are in example:

- [What would need to be discovered to prove there is extraterrestrial life?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3266/what-would-need-to-be-discovered-to-prove-there-is-extraterrestrial-life)
- [Can life subsist on anything else but water?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8977/can-life-subsist-on-anything-else-but-water)
- [How did the nucleobases in the Murchison meteorite form?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/2942/how-did-the-nucleobases-in-the-murchison-meteorite-form)
- [Why must a planet be in a star's "habitable zone" to have life?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8972/why-must-a-planet-be-in-a-stars-habitable-zone-to-have-life)
- [What would need to be discovered to prove there is extraterrestrial life?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3266/what-would-need-to-be-discovered-to-prove-there-is-extraterrestrial-life/3267)
- [What would need to be discovered to prove there is extraterrestrial life?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3266/what-would-need-to-be-discovered-to-prove-there-is-extraterrestrial-life/3268)
- [Is there life on other planets and if so how frequent?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3704/is-there-life-on-other-planets-and-if-so-how-frequent/7231)
- [What would need to be discovered to prove there is extraterrestrial life?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3266/what-would-need-to-be-discovered-to-prove-there-is-extraterrestrial-life/3271)
- [If life is discovered on another planet, will it likely be classified using the current domain/kingdom/phylum system?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/7697/if-life-is-discovered-on-another-planet-will-it-likely-be-classified-using-the/7698)

This tag can cover in some part [Extraterrestrial Life](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60806/extraterrestrial-life) proposal.

---

UPDATE:

I actually found [astrobiology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astrobiology) which can be synonim for [extraterrestrial](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extraterrestrial).

Comment: Would ex tag include the extremoohiles that live in the atmosphere or is your idea of terra including the layers

Comment: I think excluding terra including layers, so in other words - a life that does not originate from Earth. I think it could include extremophile, as long as it's not Earth-based life.

Comment: I think such atmosphere based life would have very great difficulty forming however I dare not call it impossible

Comment: Please check few [controversial pieces of evidence for extraterrestrial life](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1202/is-there-any-strong-evidence-of-alien-life/1229#1229).